# Setting QProgressBar values based on selection

Tags: python, performance, plugin

I have a function which writes a report based on technologies selected by the user via [QCheckBoxes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcheckbox.html). Depending on the number of technologies chosen, the [QProgressBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprogressbar.html) will go through set values until the function reaches completion.

For example:

```
1 tech: 0 -> 99 -> 100
2 tech: 0 -> 50 -> 99 -> 100
3 tech: 0 -> 33 -> 66 -> 99 -> 100
4 tech: 0 -> 25 -> 50 -> 75 -> 99 -> 100
```

Regardless of the number of technologies chosen, once the last one has been processed, the progressbar would be set to `99` to do some textual clean up before reaching `100`.

At the moment, I have two such technologies (PV and wind turbine) where I manually set the progress values.

How could I achieve the above in a more systematic fashion?

---

My current code:

```
def report(self):
    # Define progress bar
    progressMessageBar = iface.messageBar().createMessage(str('Generating report...'))
    progress = QProgressBar()
    progress.setMaximum(100)
    progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
    progressMessageBar.layout().addWidget(progress)
    iface.messageBar().pushWidget(progressMessageBar, iface.messageBar().INFO)
    progress.setValue(0)
    sleep(5)

    # Define Report text browser
    display_report = self.report_dockwidget.report_textBrowser
    # Technology checkboxes
    pv_checkBox = self.pv_generation_dockwidget.returnResults_Checkbox
    wind_checkBox = self.wind_generation_dockwidget.returnResults_Checkbox

    # For PV
    if pv_checkBox.isChecked():
        # Do some processing
        progress.setValue(50)
        if not wind_checkBox.isChecked():
            progress.setValue(99)
        sleep(5)

    # For Wind
    if wind_checkBox.isChecked():
        # Do some processing
        if not pv_checkBox.isChecked():
            progress.setValue(50)
        else:
            progress.setValue(99)
        sleep(5)

    # Do some cleanup
    progressMessageBar.setText('Complete')
    progress.setValue(100)
    sleep(1)

    # Show report
    self.report_dockwidget.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be to gather all your techs in a queue and iterate over that, updating the progress as you go.

Since my Python is rather Rust-y (I'm sorry for that pun), here's some pseudocode:

```
# Setup progress bar et cetera
# Gather techs in a queue
techs = Queue()
if pv_checkBox.isChecked():
    techs.add(pv_task)
if wind_checkBox.isChecked():
    techs.add(wind_task)

# Do the work
total_tasks = techs.count()
done_tasks = 0
while not techs.isEmpty():
    task = techs.take()
    task.doWork()
    done_tasks += 1
    new_progress = max(done_tasks / total_tasks * 100, 99)
    progress.setValue(newProgress)

# Progress is now 99
doFinalStuff()
progress.setValue(100)
```

This will do all the tasks in a FIFO fashion and set the progress as you wanted with the last step always being 99.

Now, it would be a good idea to gather all checkboxes in a group or layout and, by getting and filtering all child elements, add the techs via loop as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Interesting, never used `Queue()` before so will test this at some point and report back :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@PhilKiener](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/135194/phil-kiener)'s answer, I translated his pseudocode with the relevant methods for Python 2.7 which works well:

```
# Setup progress bar et cetera
# Gather techs in a queue
techs = Queue.Queue()
if pv_checkBox.isChecked():
    techs.put(pv_task)
if wind_checkBox.isChecked():
    techs.put(wind_task)

# Do the work
total_tasks = len(techs.queue)
done_tasks = 0
while not techs.empty():
    task = techs.get()
    done_tasks += 1
    new_progress = int(ceil(float(done_tasks) / float(total_tasks) * 99))
    progress.setValue(new_progress)
```